# Bucket prediction given an integer?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, prediction

If I have a dictionary of integers where the value is an array of two integers sorted, with the two values being the largest value, and the smallest value out of *`k`* values present in bucket *`n`*, how can I predict/estimate which bucket a given number would appear.

An example of said dictionary is:

```json
{
    1: [
        541247,
        14771
    ],
    15: [
        9789,
        9621
    ],
    22: [
        8984,
        8923
    ],
    64: [
        7278,
        7263
    ],
    93: [
        6846,
        6804
    ],
    126: [
        5789,
        5765
    ],
    139: [
        5484,
        5462
    ],
    208: [
        4326,
        4314
    ],
    285: [
        3788,
        3783
    ],
    322: [
        3634,
        3631
    ],
    337: [
        3586,
        3582
    ],
    356: [
        3517,
        3513
    ],
    448: [
        3232,
        3229
    ],
    459: [
        3199,
        3196
    ],
    539: [
        2990,
        2989
    ],
    581: [
        2891,
        2890
    ],
    596: [
        2858,
        2856
    ],
    640: [
        2770,
        2768
    ],
    675: [
        2704,
        2702
    ],
    679: [
        2697,
        2695
    ],
    686: [
        2684,
        2682
    ],
    733: [
        2602,
        2600
    ],
    879: [
        2387,
        2386
    ],
    961: [
        2283,
        2282
    ],
    980: [
        2261,
        2260
    ],
    995: [
        2244,
        2243
    ],
    1000: [
        2238,
        2237
    ],
    1169: [
        2064,
        2063
    ],
    1175: [
        2058,
        2057
    ],
    1236: [
        2005,
        2004
    ],
    1259: [
        1985,
        1984
    ],
    1281: [
        1967,
        1966
    ],
    1348: [
        1913,
        1912
    ],
    1424: [
        1855,
        1855
    ],
    1429: [
        1852,
        1851
    ],
    1514: [
        1796,
        1795
    ],
    1564: [
        1764,
        1764
    ],
    1596: [
        1744,
        1744
    ],
    1625: [
        1726,
        1726
    ],
    1661: [
        1704,
        1703
    ],
    1695: [
        1683,
        1682
    ],
    1710: [
        1675,
        1674
    ],
    1713: [
        1673,
        1673
    ],
    1720: [
        1669,
        1669
    ],
    1835: [
        1609,
        1608
    ],
    1846: [
        1603,
        1602
    ],
    1861: [
        1594,
        1594
    ],
    1864: [
        1593,
        1592
    ],
    1916: [
        1562,
        1561
    ],
    2093: [
        1462,
        1462
    ],
    2159: [
        1424,
        1423
    ],
    2175: [
        1414,
        1413
    ],
    2189: [
        1405,
        1405
    ],
    2209: [
        1394,
        1393
    ],
    2266: [
        1359,
        1358
    ],
    2319: [
        1327,
        1326
    ],
    2352: [
        1306,
        1306
    ],
    2429: [
        1260,
        1260
    ],
    2512: [
        1214,
        1214
    ],
    2629: [
        1141,
        1141
    ],
    2704: [
        1088,
        1088
    ],
    2736: [
        1064,
        1063
    ],
    2745: [
        1057,
        1057
    ],
    2766: [
        1042,
        1042
    ],
    2779: [
        1033,
        1032
    ],
    2790: [
        1025,
        1024
    ],
    2798: [
        1019,
        1018
    ],
    2880: [
        964,
        964
    ],
    2945: [
        928,
        927
    ],
    3032: [
        885,
        884
    ],
    3115: [
        838,
        837
    ],
    3120: [
        835,
        834
    ],
    3140: [
        823,
        822
    ],
    3169: [
        806,
        805
    ],
    3235: [
        770,
        770
    ],
    3252: [
        762,
        762
    ],
    3258: [
        759,
        758
    ],
    3366: [
        715,
        714
    ],
    3414: [
        690,
        690
    ],
    3444: [
        675,
        674
    ],
    3507: [
        645,
        644
    ],
    3543: [
        630,
        629
    ],
    3758: [
        516,
        515
    ],
    3764: [
        512,
        511
    ],
    3770: [
        509,
        508
    ],
    3931: [
        446,
        446
    ],
    4013: [
        416,
        415
    ],
    4055: [
        390,
        390
    ],
    4116: [
        378,
        377
    ],
    4255: [
        370,
        370
    ],
    4286: [
        362,
        361
    ],
    4325: [
        360,
        360
    ],
    4337: [
        355,
        355
    ],
    4349: [
        347,
        347
    ],
    4355: [
        344,
        343
    ],
    4366: [
        339,
        339
    ],
    4379: [
        333,
        333
    ],
    4460: [
        312,
        311
    ],
    4474: [
        309,
        309
    ],
    4487: [
        308,
        308
    ],
    4545: [
        259,
        257
    ],
    4555: [
        242,
        241
    ]
}
```

If I am searching for the bucket containing `2672` how would I go about doing this? The bucket data is gathered from web scraping so I know that bucket `692` contains `2672`, but I am looking for a more general solution that would allow me to only have to scrape *`x`* number of buckets before I have enough data to predict which bucket would hold any value. I will add that the first and last entries in the dict are guaranteed to hold both the largest and smallest searchable values.

Is this a known problem already? If so what is it called?

My current solution is below:

```py
def bucket_search(buckets, n):
    start_idx = None
    end_idx = None
    bucket_keys = list(buckets.keys())
    bucket_values = list(buckets.values())
    for idx, bv in enumerate(bucket_values):
        high,low = bv
        if n > low and n < high:
            start_idx = idx
            end_idx = idx
            break
        elif high < n:
            end_idx = idx
            break

    if (end_idx != start_idx):
        continue_search = True
        tmp_start_idx = end_idx - 1
        while continue_search:
            high, low = bucket_values[tmp_start_idx]
            if (low > n):
                continue_search = False
            elif (low < n and high < n):
                tmp_start_idx -= 1
        start_idx = tmp_start_idx

        start_bucket_value = bucket_keys[start_idx]
        end_bucket_value = bucket_keys[end_idx]

        start_value = bucket_values[start_idx][1]
        end_value = bucket_values[end_idx][0]

        bucket_value_difference = end_bucket_value - start_bucket_value
        value_difference = start_value - end_value

        increment_amount = bucket_value_difference / value_difference

        tmp_value = start_value
        tmp_bucket_value = start_bucket_value

        for i in range(bucket_value_difference):
            tmp_value -= increment_amount
            tmp_bucket_value += 1
            if (n > tmp_value):
                break
        return tmp_bucket_value

    else:
        return bucket_keys[start_idx]
```

Currently `bucket_search(data, 2672)` (where *`data`* is the example data provided above) returns `704`. That is close to `692` but I would think that there is a better, more accurate/precise solution.

While I used python, answers of any language are fine as long as the answer can be rewritten in another language, i.e. please don't use any niche libraries.

If there is already an answered SO question that solves this problem, I apologize as I am unsure what to call this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you find consistent relationships between keys and values? Is it true in all cases that the values decrease as the keys increase? Is there some other discernable pattern to the data? Based on what you've shown and described, it looks like the best you can do is binary search and interpolation, which is what it looks like you're already doing. Unless you can find more patterns in the data.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes It is true for all cases that values decrease as keys increase. As for a pattern, when more scraped data is plotted it roughly follows a [logarithmic trend line](https://i.ibb.co/sgCT91y/chart.png).
This is why I thought/think that there is a better solution than mine.